# knitr does not compile pdf

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

I'm new to coding and I`m trying to use knitr to print a PDF. I have installed R 3.5.3 and RStudio installed correctly as simple codes usually run.

I have both installed in the same folder as Miktex 2.9.7

As I create a new markdown file with a PDF output, incoded in UTF-8, I get the standard model text.

I've tried different encodings and reinstalled miktex several times.

When I run a code I used at my uni lab, it runs, but if I alter even 1 character on a string and save it, it wont compile the pdf anymore.

This is what I've been trying to compile:

````
---
title: "Lista 1"
date: "April 6, 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r instalar pacotes necessarios}
# Carregando os pacotes necessários
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load("tinytex", "tidyverse")
```

Questão 1

Use os conhecimentos adquiridos em sala de aula (e fora dela!) para realizar >as seguintes operações sobre o
banco de dados mpg:

```{r variaveis q1a}
posicao <- 100
item.a <- mpg[posicao, c("manufacturer","model")]
```


a) A partir do código acima podemos verificar que o veículo de posição `r posicao` banco de daados é um `r item.a`


```{r}
media.milhas.cidade <- mean(mpg$cty)
```

b) A partir do código acima, pode-se verificar que a média de milhas por galão na cidade é `r media.milhas.cidade`
````

---

I should just get the pdf but Rstudio prints this:

```
================================


processing file: lista1mkd.Rmd
  |.........                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                              |  29%
label: instalar pacotes necessarios
  |............................                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....................................                            |  57%
label: variaveis q1a
  |..............................................                   |  71%
   inline R code fragments

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  manufacturer model
  <chr>        <chr>
1 honda        civic
  |........................................................         |  86%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |.................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments


"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS lista1mkd.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output lista1mkd.tex --template "C:\Users\CESARA~1\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.5\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\DEFAUL~3.TEX" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable "compact-title:yes" 
output file: lista1mkd.knit.md

Error: Failed to compile lista1mkd.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(logfile) : incomplete final line found on 'lista1mkd.log'
Execution halted
```

Comment: (1) Have you tried this with the recommendations of [`knitr` debugging](https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging)? If so, please include its output. (2) Do you ever define `mpg`? You reference it but I do not see its definition. (You really should define it in the rmarkdown file itself and not rely on its presence in your R environment.)

Comment: `mpg` is part of `ggplot2` which OP loads with `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: Are you able to knit non-pdf documents (e.g., html)?